# Modify Current Shell in Lua

Tags: lua, hpc

Is it possible to modify the current shell with system calls in Lua?

More specifically, in the current environment expand_aliases is false by default but some scripts depend on the ability to set aliases. Is it possible to issue a command like os.execute("shopt -s expand_aliases") at the beginning of those scripts that would affect the current shell thus allowing the current script to add a bash alias?

Both setting expand_aliases globally to true as well as setting expand_aliases in bash before executing the script aren't quite desired solutions.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related mailing list thread: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-03/msg00101.html

Answer (score 1):

You could open a *pipe* to a shell and then send both your configuration settings and your scripts to it. But you cannot affect the *current* shell.